# iPhone crash log questions?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I have recently update a new version of my application and its got rejected as apple said "Your app crashed when we launched it. This occurred when your app was used on Wi-Fi." But i have double checked with an Adhoc build via testflight and its working on iPad iOS 7.1 on wi-fi. Here is the crash log that apple sent to me.

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/27000A12-B7DF-4CB2-BDAA-407CA13E56D2/xxx.app/xxx
  Reason: image not found
  Dyld Version: 324.1

Binary Images:
0x120044000 - 0x120068faa dyld arm64  <628da833271c3f9bb8d44c34060f55e0> /usr/lib/dyld
0x183d98000 - 0x183dbffff Accounts arm64  <04e6c9c23f373940997e5568b8a52603> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x183dc0000 - 0x183dc3fff AdSupport arm64  <0d83c40bfdf03cf095fedcc8ad23be9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
0x183f84000 - 0x183f97ffc AssetsLibrary arm64  <054d2b33a8213bc4860d8b66a510713a> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x184460000 - 0x1845cbff5 CFNetwork arm64  <ce62a2429e433953866294646317b611> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x1850ac000 - 0x18511bff7 CoreTelephony arm64  <61e20d91b4d6306881a64da129c0dcf1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x187520000 - 0x18769bff3 QuartzCore arm64  <1ae8ea71790d382e84c3d403f0afaffd> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x187700000 - 0x187757ffb Security arm64  <b27dccf33c573663b07cdbf5d3c9a797> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x187758000 - 0x1877e3fff Social arm64  <327452a6cdcf3e42a7f71edc0ba0641e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
0x1878c4000 - 0x18792bff7 SystemConfiguration arm64  <58592ccb97af3ceb9008b388c1692d0f> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x191650000 - 0x19170fff4 libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <d25694cbb3f2336fa7c758b24ae66b37> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x19179c000 - 0x191887fff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <94ada6329bdf3570b4318a3e10558771> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x1918b4000 - 0x1918c7ff7 libz.1.dylib arm64  <070746af9ba53c1ca2d1bf0d2067fb80> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your app is trying to load the unit testing framework (SetTestingKit.framework) in release, where it likely doesn't exist. You need to make sure you don't link against it in the Release configuration.